# asp.net HTTP Cliente get com query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-web-api

Desenvolvido numa asp.net mvc pretendo implementar um HTTP `request` que com esta parte de código as meteorologias me apresentem uma "lista" com as meteriologias da query `data_de_leitura=2016-11-11&hora_de_leitura={null}` ou seja 3 metereologias para a query que é adicionada ao url
exemplo:

```
api/Metereologias?data_de_leitura=2016-11-11&hora_de_leitura={null}
```

O resultado obtido independentemente do valor de data e hora é sempre o mesmo, todas as metereologias do url da api.

```
var client = WebApiHttpClient.GetClient();
string path = "api/Metereologias?data_de_leitura=" + data + "hora_de_leitura=" + hora;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var metereologias =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MetereologiaDTO>>(content);
    await GetPois();

    return View(metereologias);
```

no lado da api apresenta um metodo no controller para tratar estes dados

```
public List<MetereologiaDTO> GetMetereologiasSearchDataeHora(string data_de_leitura, string hora_de_leitura)
    {
        List<MetereologiaDTO> result = new List<MetereologiaDTO>();

        result = verificarData(result, data_de_leitura);
        result = verificarHora(result, hora_de_leitura);

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Daniel acho que possa ser cache então coloque um guid ao final.

```
string path = "api/Metereologias?data_de_leitura=" + data + "hora_de_leitura=" + hora + "&guid?=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Veja se resolve.

Comment: o resultado apresentado é na mesma como se fosse apenas "api/Metereologias"

Comment: @Daniel Dias, não importam os parâmetros que passe na API, a variavel **metereologias** sempre tem a mesma informação porém deveria trazer outros dados certo? Se sim, deveria trazer outros dados, deve ser algo com a API. Tentou ver a API?

Comment: a api está testada testada
exemplo para "http://localhost:50634/api/Metereologias?data_de_leitura=2016-11-11&hora_de_leitura={null}"

apresenta 3 metereologias e nao as 5 total da base de dados